# Windows Media Player open multiple files at once through CMD

Tags: cmd, wmp

I'm trying to open multiple files at once, so they automatically become on the "Currently Playing List" on windows media player. I need it to be a CMD command. For example:

There are two files:
Music 1.mp3
Music 2.mp3

I want the command to open them both at the same time so they both become on the list of playing music. I want it either to open both at same time OR open one, then add the other to the list, I need suggestions, thank you very much for your time spent reading.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

simply like this:

```
"%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe" "Music 1.mp3" "Music 2.mp3" "etc.mp3"
```